# How to get the directory in a path in perl

Tags: perl

I have a directory path:

```
my $temp = "/a/b/c/d";
my $upDirectory = dirname( $temp );
```

This returns "/a/b/c". 
But I need just "c". I have to compare it with a string to determine if it is the right directory.

Is there a way other than split on "/"? I do not want to use this. The Perl code has to be used on multiple platforms.
Can splitdir help?

Comment: You want the value of `basename($upDirectory)`, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are, of course, many ways to do it but if your main concern is portability to other platforms then [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PathTools/lib/File/Spec.pm) is probably a reasonable bet.  Look for `splitpath` and `splitdir`.

Comment: Thanks @ask-bjorn-hansen
I tried splitdir. It worked. But I also tried doing it with "basename". It worked as well without much hassle. 
`use File::Basename;
my $temp = "/a/b/c/d";
my $upDirectory = dirname( $temp );
my $dirName = basename($upDirectory);`
# it returns "c".

Comment: The reason I didn't suggest File::Basename was that I wasn't sure if /d in your example was a filename or directory and if it's a directory if your code would be consistent about adding (or not) a trailing slash.  Without having tested it I think you have to be careful with that when using dirname/basename.  With File::Spec's split functions I think it'd be more obvious what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory [`Path::Class`](http://p3rl.org/Path%3a%3aClass) solution:

```
use Path::Class qw(dir);
dir('/a/b/c/d')->parent->dir_list(-1)
# expression returns 'c'
```